# Как выронить элементы посередине экрана

Tags: android, android-layout

У меня есть XML layout
Мне нужно чтобы все его содержимое было не на весь экран.
А определенное размера и в центре.
Просто скопируйте данный код и проверьте.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_content"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            tools:context="ru.veantm.darkmessenger.Activity.LoginActivity">

            <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                android:id="@+id/appbar"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

                </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:id="@+id/tabs"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/container"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="300dp"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для подобных целей есть аттрибут `gravity`. В вашем случае надо ему присвоить значение `center` или `center_horizontal`. Установить его надо самому верхнему элементу разметки. Также, надо указать ширину равную ширине экрана, т.е. `match_parent`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="Wrap_content">
      <!-- тут всё, что надо выровнять посередине -->
</LinearLayout>
```